# How is @types/react-data-grid updated to be in sync with the react-data-grid repo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid

In the `React-Data-Grid` repo, I see

```
export interface DataGridProps {

  columns: ColumnList;
  (...)
  rowRenderer?: React.ReactElement | React.ComponentType;
  rowGroupRenderer?: React.ComponentType;
  (...)
```

and

```
export default class ReactDataGrid extends React.Component<DataGridProps, DataGridState> { ... }
```

So in the definition of `ReactDataGrid` we see the presence of `rowGroupRenderer` prop.

However, this prop is not available in the package `@types/react-data-grid`. There is a type called `GridProps` there, but not `DataGridProps`. Also, this `GridProps` does not correspond to the exported `GridProps` in the `Grid.tsx` file in the `React-Data-Grid` repo.

**How are types in @types/data-grid-types updated?** How is this kept in sync with the project?

Answer (score 0):

**In this specific case, you shouldn't need to use the `@types` package** because `react-data-grid` itself is [written in TypeScript](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/tree/next/packages/react-data-grid/src) and publishes its types as part of the npm package (you can tell from the [`types` setting in its package.json](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/next/packages/react-data-grid/package.json#L9)). So you should be able to remove the `@types/react-data-grid` dependency and the real types will be picked up automatically from the package itself.

**In general**, `@types` packages are hosted in the [DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (`@types/react-data-grid` is [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-data-grid)). Updating these type packages is a manual process, sometimes driven by the package's users if the author/maintainer doesn't care about TypeScript support. So if you find an issue and have time to [contribute a fix](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute), that's great!

(As far as why `react-data-grid` has an `@types` package even though it exports its own typings, I'm guessing "historical reasons"--maybe it was written in JS originally and converted to TS at some point.)

Comment: I saw that it is written in TypeScript, but in my project using `yarn add react-data-grid --save`, I get version "^6.1.0", and when I look in my node_modules, the dist folder has `react-data-grid.js` and `react-data-grid.min.js`, that's it.

Comment: I did in fact make a PR for the issue in my question. But I now wonder why the package isn't distributed with type definition files.

Comment: Oh interesting, in that case maybe the project author has their build or publishing configuration set up incorrectly? I'd recommend filing a GitHub issue in react-data-grid about the missing file. (I'm not familiar enough with the build/publishing configuration they're using to find what might be wrong.)